# passing boost python enum as parameter

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I defined

```
enum_<mytype>("mytype")
    .value("one",1)
    .value("two",2)
;
```

in my BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE.

when I expose a class with a function taking a parameter of type mytype (essentially, an int), like:

```
void myfunc(mytype m) {
    ...
}
```

I get the following compiler warning:

**dereferencing pointer 'p.2311' (or whatever) does break strict-aliasing rules**

now, it is just a warning, and the code works perfectly with optimization enabled..

may I safely ignore the warning? am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing the warning, but it's most likely caused by [some macros from Python headers](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3123/). To be safe, compile the code that uses Python (and Boost.Python) with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.